# MySQL - Find Missing Data

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to list every occurrence of missing data, from a table which should contain 24 rows of data (one for each hour) for every day. From the following example:

```
Datetime
2015-05-01 00:00:00
2015-05-01 01:00:00
2015-05-01 02:00:00
2015-05-01 03:00:00
2015-05-01 07:00:00
2015-05-01 08:00:00
2015-05-01 09:00:00
...
```

I would like to return:

```
Datetime
2015-05-01 04:00:00
2015-05-01 05:00:00
2015-05-01 06:00:00
```

I can return the first hour and the last hour of missing data like this:

```
SELECT t1.datetime AS `from`, t2.datetime AS `to`
FROM test.table AS t1
JOIN test.table AS t2
  ON t1.datetime < t2.datetime
LEFT JOIN test.table AS t3
  ON t3.datetime > t1.datetime
   AND t3.datetime < t2.datetime
WHERE t3.datetime IS NULL
  AND t2.datetime > DATE_ADD(t1.datetime, INTERVAL 60 MINUTE)
ORDER BY t1.datetime;
```

But this is as far as Google has been able to get me.

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Although are some hacks, generally a database cannot return data it does not possess. Instead it must be deduced. Typically such deductions are managed at the application level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a temporary table with all the hours then join temporary table and the table holding the real data.

```
SELECT temp_table.datetime AS MissingDT
FROM temp_table
LEFT JOIN data_table ON temp_table.datetime = data_table.datetime
WHERE data_table.datetime IS NULL;
```

> DATA_TABLE = Table that holds real data
>
> TEMP_TABLE = Table that holds dummy data - i.e. all the hours